# Type of the shown reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

Could you please let me know what the type of this shown reaction is?

Comment: Homework or homework like questions need to be accompanied by the asker's approach/reasoning to the question or according the the [homework policy](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) they are closed.

Comment: Alright, this is very obviously not a homework. I am a student and this was a question in my past papers where ı was expected to fill in the red molecules. and I am struggling to get to know what type of reaction this is. is there something wrong here?

Comment: @Taylan This question is so specific that it does not add to the mission of SE. If you had a question like 'Why is NaOEt required for this class of reaction.' it might work, as it gets at mechanisms and explaining this one, or  ' Given the product of this reaction, how can the reactants be predicted.' , leading to an answer that can explain that the addition occurs at the -CHO site.

Comment: alright thank you, ı am new to the website so wasnt sure about how to formulate the question in a suitable way for the website. ı removed the pic after being told that ı should not have asked it but someone edited it and put it back. thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic example of the Knoevenagel condensation

https://www.name-reaction.com/knoevenagel-condensation

https://chemistry.tutorvista.com/organic-chemistry/knoevenagel-condensation.html

Comment: You should try to make more elaborate answers and don't answer questions which may violate homework policy.